# How to architecture the server end point an editor app that converts a json from editor into an s3 link?

Tags: reactjs, backend, content-management-system, react-fullstack

I currently have a react application with client side routing (using https://reactrouter.com/) which has 2 modes - Edit and View.

In the edit mode the user creates some interactive app which is saved into a JSON and this is uploaded to S3. View mode loads this JSON and the builds the interactive app.

The issue here is that there are many interactive 'pieces' that can be possible and this makes my overall website very large. If I use lazy loading the download size can be reduced but the initial load is slow.

I understand that with server side rendering frameworks (such as Next.js) you have an active server that does part of the above conversion work in the server and makes the view mode app efficient. This is done whenever a http request is made - hence the need for a server. But for my use-case, the JSON never changes unless someone changes from the editor (which is going to be very few). So I wanted to move the editor app to a server (with some preview frontend), but have this server render the JSON when updated and save the output into a S3. So that the view mode is essentially just a static link.

I don't have much experience with backend or fullstack and so would like some guidance on how to approach this.